# Websites not working in Azure Static Web App. Error message ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-static-web-app

I have a static webpage that I created with azure static web apps :

**ambitious-cliff-052ac5f03.3.azurestaticapps.net**

I configured this with my IP provider using **CNAME** and **A**.

My azure domains look like this :

[image]

And the domain configuartion on my IP provider looks like this :

[image]

If I go to "frontangle.com" it works, (but sometimes it doesnt!). And if I go to "www.frontangle.com" it never works.

Usually if there is a SSL certificate issue you can still access the website but there is just an annoying warning in the top.

But now the error ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID is not allowing me to do anything. Instead of a continue button there is a reload button. Or a screen like this :

[image]

Can anyone help me out here? I am confused as to why this has to be so complicated for a simple website.

Comment: Doesn't seem like the automatic cert supports wildcard, have you tried explicitly adding `www.frontangle.com` for the custom domain? You can't ignore the error because HSTS is enabled (there's some unsafe mode workaround by typing some word)

Comment: Im unsure what that would mean. Do you mean I add "www.frontangle.com" in the azure console as CNAME or TXT?

Comment: As CNAME, TXT isn't used for resolution.

Comment: its not possible in azure. If I try and create a CNAME entry it says : CNAME Record is invalid.  Please ensure the CNAME record has been created.

Comment: You need the CNAME record in both azure and your IP provider

Comment: but my IP provider does not provide CNAME

Comment: Use other nameservers that provide full functionality. Usually, you can keep your registrar while switching to other nameservers, some are free and reputable.

Comment: What is the framework of the Static Web App?